# Auto create file and send it via wp_mail()

Tags: attachments, email

I am getting dynamic content on page load and sending it via mail using wp_mail(). Right now all contents going in body section of email
but I want it to store in .doc(MS word) file and then send that file as an attachment.

I can send attachment via wp_mail(). But I am not getting any solution about how to auto create file and store all html content in file. I search a lot on google but couldn't find anything helpful. Is there any possible way of doing this in wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

Can't help you with the creation of the .doc-file, as i have never done that. But if you manage to get the encoded file into a string, you can work with the Wordpress PHP-Mailer instance like this:

```
function send_my_mail_with_attachment($from,$to,$subject,$body,$attachmentstring=""){
        global $phpmailer;
        // (Re)create it, if it's gone missing
        if ( ! ( $phpmailer instanceof PHPMailer ) ) {
            require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpmailer.php';
            require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-smtp.php';
            $phpmailer = new PHPMailer( true );
        }
        $phpmailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $phpmailer->ClearAllRecipients();
        $phpmailer->ClearAttachments();
        $phpmailer->ClearCustomHeaders();
        $phpmailer->ClearReplyTos();
        $fromaddress=$from;
        $phpmailer->setFrom($fromaddress);
        $phpmailer->Sender = $phpmailer->From;
        $phpmailer->addAddress($to);
        $phpmailer->isHTML(true);   // Set email format to HTML
        $phpmailer->Subject = $subject;
        $phpmailer->Body    = $body;
        if($attachmentstring){
               $phpmailer->AddStringAttachment($attachmentstring,'my_attachment.doc');
        }
        $rueckgabe = $phpmailer->Send(); 
        return $rueckgabe;
}
```

You can learn more about PHPMailer [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: If it can be done with pdf then also its fine.

Comment: Yep. Actually, i modified this code as it previous worked with pdf. You can use mpdf, which is a fork of fpdf, also. You get the String for the string-attachment like this:
$attachmentstring = $mpdf->Output('my_temp_file.pdf', 'S');

(You of course have to change the function to $phpmailer->AddStringAttachment($attachmentstring,'my_attachment.pdf');
)

Answer (score 1):

If a document is meant to open on someone else's computer it's always a good practice to send it in a PDF format, that way you can maintain the styling and font of the document.

If you agree, you can use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to create PDF files with dynamic content.

here is a code example:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->Rect(10, 10, 190, 135, 'D');
$pdf->Image('http://example.com/img/logo.jpg',12,12,0,0,'JPG');
$pdf->Cell(78);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(30,10,'Document Title');
$pdf->Ln(5);
$op = $pdf->Output();
```

you can generate and save the pdf on your server and then use the method suggested by @kuchenundkakao to attach it to the email.

Comment: _"If you agree"_ Yes, no issues if it will be pdf instead of doc file :)

Comment: cool. let me know if it worked for you.